# Opening an aspx page in another tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I've been searching around on how to open a page in a new tab by clicking a button. Most codes written online are the same but when i try all of them, it doesn't work and no error is stated either.

this is my codes:

aspx.cs:

```
protected void btngen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string queryString = "Barcode test.aspx";
            string newWin = "window.open('" + queryString + "','_blank');";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);
        }
```

aspx:

```
<div class ="form-group">
                   <label for="TxtBarcode" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Barcode : </label>  
                <div class="col-sm-2">             
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />
                </div>
                  <div class ="col-sm-2">
                       <asp:Button ID="btngen" runat="Server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Generate barcode" OnClick="btngen_Click" />
                  </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Check for popup blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Change btnget to `LinkButton` after that add attribute to this link button in the code behind:

```
btnget.Attributes.Add("target", "_blank");
```

Other possibility javascript

```
   <asp:LinkButton ID="btngen" runat="Server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Generate barcode" OnClick="btngen_Click" OnClientClick="return OpenNewTab();" />

   //in the ASPX:

   <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenNewTab() {
        document.forms[0].target = '_blank';
    }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Linkbutton in redirect to any href or .aspx page

.aspx:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" href="index.aspx" target="_blank" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

or

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" href="http:\\www.google.com" target="_blank" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```